# Find from parentheses regex php

Tags: php, regex

I need help in regex php

It is necessary to use the number from parentheses, the parentheses are repeated in some cases

Example of two different strings:

```
2.0 16V Quadrifoglio (114 kW / 155 PS) 
1.4 TB (940FXB1A) (125 kW / 170 PS)
```

I needed it to look like this:

```
2.0 16V Quadrifoglio 155 WORD 
1.4 TB 170 WORD
```

I have code

```
$text = '2.0 16V Quadrifoglio (114 kW / 155 PS)';
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match);
print $match[1];
```

And results is:

```
114 kW / 155 PS
```

Please help to find number from parentheses

Comment: You need to use `preg_replace()` to match the parentheses, and a capture group to pick out the contents that you want to copy to the replacement.

Comment: See https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture just the number after the `/`, and replace the whole parenthesis expression with that.

```
$newText = preg_replace('#\([^)]*/\s*([^)]*)\)#', '$1', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I needed it to look like this:
>
> ```
> 2.0 16V Quadrifoglio 155 WORD 
> 1.4 TB 170 WORD
> ```

Pattern: `~^([^(]*).*?(\d+) PS.*~`

Replacement: `$1$2 WORD`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GiJDi5/2

Output:

```
2.0 16V Quadrifoglio 155 WORD
1.4 TB 170 WORD
```

---

PHP: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FC4Zu))

```
$strings = [
    '2.0 16V Quadrifoglio (114 kW / 155 PS)',
    '1.4 TB (940FXB1A) (125 kW / 170 PS)'
];

var_export(preg_replace('~^([^(]*).*?(\d+) PS.*~', '$1$2 WORD', $strings));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '2.0 16V Quadrifoglio 155 WORD',
  1 => '1.4 TB 170 WORD',
)
```